# Split string of digits into lists of even and odd integers

Tags: python

Having such code

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
nums = {'evens': [], 'odds': []}

for number in numbers.split(' '):
    if int(number) % 2:
        nums['odds'].append(number)
    else:
        nums['evens'].append(number)
```

How can accomplish same on fewer lines?

Comment: Your code is easy to understand and is only a handful of lines long.  It uses basic building blocks of python coding.  I actually prefer it to some of the more esoteric answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short code is not better code. Short code is not faster code. Short code is not maintainable code. Now, that said, it *is* good to make your individual components concise and simple.

Here's what I would do:

```
def split_odd_even(number_list):
    return {
        'odds': filter(lambda n: (n % 2) != 0, number_list),
        'evens': filter(lambda n: (n % 2) == 0, number_list)
    }

def string_to_ints(string):
    return map(int, numbers.strip().split())

numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
nums = split_odd_even(string_to_ints(numbers))

print nums
```

This gives me:

```
{'odds': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'evens': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]}
```

While this code has actually added a few lines in length, it has become much more clear what the program is doing, as we've applied [*Abstraction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) and made each component of the code do only one thing well.

Even though we've added two functions, the most-visible part of the code has gone from this:

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
nums = {'evens': [], 'odds': []}
for number in numbers.split(' '):
    if int(number) % 2:
        nums['odds'].append(number)
    else:
        nums['evens'].append(number)
```

To this:

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
nums = split_odd_even(string_to_ints(numbers))
```

And just by reading these two lines, we know that `numbers` is converted from a string to a list of `int`s, and that we then split those numbers into odd and even, and assign the result to `nums`.

To explain a a couple of things that may not be familiar to all:

- [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) calls a function for every item in a `list` (or `tuple` or other iterable), and returns *a new list with the result of the function being called on each item*. In this case, we use it to call `int()` on each item in the list.
- [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) calls a function for every item in a `list` (or `tuple` or other iterable), which returns `True` or `False` for each item (well, [*truthy* or *falsey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), and returns a list of items that evaluated to `True` when the function is called.
- Lambda Expressions ([`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)) are like "mini-functions" that take arguments and can be created in-place.

Answer (score 4):

A functional aproach:

```
>>> numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
>>> numbers = map(int, numbers.split())
>>> nums = {'evens': filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers), 'odds': filter(lambda x: x%2 != 0, numbers)}
>>> nums
{'evens': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'odds': [1, 3, 5, 7]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish the same results with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby), like so:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
>>> d = {'even':[], 'odd':[]}
>>> mynum = [int(x) for x in numbers.strip().split()]
>>> for k,g in groupby(mynum, lambda x: x % 2):
        if k:
            d['odd'].extend(g)
        else:
            d['even'].extend(g)


>>> d
{'even': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'odd': [1, 3, 5, 7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
nums = {}
nums["even"] = [int(i) for i in numbers.split() if int(i) % 2 == 0]
nums["odd"] = [int(i) for i in numbers.split() if int(i) % 2 == 1]
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
{'even': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'odd': [1, 3, 5, 7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to try it out:

```
numbers = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'
nums = {'evens': [], 'odds': []}
for number in numbers.split(' '):
    category = 'odds' if int(number) % 2 else 'evens'
    nums[category].append(number)
```

But if you want to use it in production: **Readable code is more important than 'short' code**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a one-liner, but I wouldn't recommend it. Your code is perfectly fine.

```
[nums['odds'].append(n) if int(n)%2 else nums['evens'].append(n) for n in numbers.split(' ')]
```

Comment: Yes, I said so in my answer.